# Do I need to dispose cubit instances?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am new to flutter and bloc. As a matter of fact, I have just recently started using cubit. For learning purposes, I have created a simple app in which I use cubit for bloc functionality. In all the examples I found online, they suggest disposing the bloc instance in the UI. However, I didn't find something similar when it comes to cubit. So, my question is: Do I need to dispose the cubit instances and how? It worths mentioning here that I am using MultiBlocProvider.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bloc extends Cubit and Cubit extends Stream. Like any Stream in Dart it needs to be disposed when it is not necessary, and it has `close` method to do so.
This method will be executed automatically if you are using BlocProvider

Comment: Thank you for you answer! This means that I don't have to create a @dispose method. Is this right?

Comment: Correct. MultiBlocProvider will handle disposing

Comment: @johnweak do you mind marking post as an answer if it helped?

Comment: But if I want to, for example, cancel a subscription before close (or remove a listener). Should I override the close method (calling super.close(), of course) ?

Comment: @CaioSantos Yes. Subscriptions that are defined inside Cubit class won't be closed otherwise